# Hashtable in C: Does testing functions using manual arguments differ from user inputted arguments

Tags: c, tree, insert, binary-tree, hashtable

My problem is rather an odd one. When I tested my functions manually it worked, but it returned a random result when I let the user input the arguments.

To better explain myself, I am writing a hash table using binary trees instead of a linked lists (which is a part of my assignment). That is, in the event of a hash collision the data chains into a binary search tree.

I have finished all of my functions, but in terms of testing, I manually inputted the arguments. That is I set the arguments inside the my tester already rather than having the user type it in when the program runs. This works fine and the functions returns what they are suppose to return. However, when I tried to the user input, my insert and delete was behaving strangely. For instance, for delete, it is supposed to return the value that it just deleted. However, it gave me a value that was the value of another node in the BST.

Manual Input Code Snippet: I inserted the key = "111" and value = "D" manually

```
char ** preval = calloc(1, sizeof(char *));

InsertEntry(*htHandle, "111", (void *) "D", (void **) preval);

printf("Existing value %s removed\n", *preval);
free(preval);
```

Result: This returned the correct output, as expected by the instructions given. There were more key-value pairs that I entered before (this is a small chunk of code, assume htHandle was the hash table pointer).

User Input from a Tester I wrote (Another snippet of code):

```
if (strcmp(str, "insert") == 0)
{
char key[50];
printf("Key: ");
scanf("%s", key);

char value[50];
printf("Item: ");
scanf("%s", value);

char ** preval = calloc(1, sizeof(char *));

int success = InsertEntry(*htHandle, key, (void *) value, (void **) preval);
...
if (success == 2)      
    printf("Node Exists - Inserted after removing existing data: %s\n", *preval);
...
free(preval);
}

​Result: Here preval points to the data of the last key-value pair in the BST or the most recently entered one, or some other random one.
```

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> However, when I tried to the user input, my insert and delete was behaving strangely. For instance, for delete, it is supposed to return the value that it just deleted. However, it gave me a value that was the value of another node in the BST.

It looks like you are storing pointers to strings, rather than strings. Perhaps you are reusing the same buffer for user input? We really need to see how you store and pass user input, and maybe the code for `InsertEntry()` to properly answer your question.

But there's another interesting issue here:

> ```
> char ** preval = calloc(1, sizeof(char *));
> int success = InsertEntry(*htHandle, key, (void *) value, (void **) preval);
> ...
> free (preval);
> ```

There's a simpler way to allocate storage for a pointer, and to return a value through a function argument:

```
char *preval;
int success = InsertEntry(*htHandle, key, (void *) value, (void **)&preval);
```

However, the conversion from `char **` to `void **` is a bit suspicious. It works because `void *` and `char *` are guranteed to have the same representation and alignment. There is no such guarantee for other pointer types. If you wanted to store `int`s, for example, you'd have to write:

```
int *preval;
void *vp;
int success = InsertEntry(*htHandle, key, (void *) value, &vp);
preval = vp;
```

An `int *` can be converted to a `void *` and back, but the same does **not** hold for `int **` and `void **`, so you need an extra variable to store the return value. This also has the nice effect of eliminating the need for the `(void **)` cast. Personally, I would also remove *all* of the `(void *)` casts above. It is unlikely that they are needed.